# Spyder/Anaconda: How to stop the kernel and save the output

Tags: python, spyder

I have finally succeeded to run my code that optimizes a model, however, the kernel has been running for about 24 hours and still running. I think I have to strengthen my formulation in different ways. But for now, I tried to press the stop button at the upper right side of the console to interrupt the kernel but no use. It continues running.

I want to stop the kernel and at the same time save the log of the output data in a file as proof of what I have reached to send to my supervisor.

What I want to do is to "interrupt" the kernel as described in this blog
https://www.dummies.com/programming/python/interacting-kernel-python-programming/

But how I can do this in the Spyder environment?

Comment: I do not know what is the issue in my question to be rated it negatively?

Comment: My question is very clear and I think any experienced one can answer me, it is not a big issue or an intertwingled question. The kernel is still running and cannot stop it without leaving the spyder interface

Comment: Hello, I keep having the same problem. What I noted I get it when I have a script containing different methods, say from scikit-learn and I can detect my computer running one of inner methods, for example, because the method is parallelized and my CPU cooling fan turns on.  When the method is done and computer switches to work on my script to the part without any outside functions or methods then the kernel may finally stop.  As for somebody rating your question down, I see it as misogynistic action, which happens here on stackoverflow. I agree that your question is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a Keras or TensorFlow model? If so write the following code to save your model:

```
model.save('name.h5') #Note that it has to be in an h5 extension
```

You can load this model later if you want to in a new file by typing the following:

```
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.models.load_model('path/to/location')
```

You can then use the `model.predict()` function or any other one in a new file to show to your supervisor. Remember this is only for keras or tensorflow models

Comment: It is a network problem, namely vehicle routing problem and it is  non-polynomial hard (NP-hard) in nature. All I did so far was to select some of the data at the console and right-clicked the mouse to select ''print '' and saved it to a pdf and then restarted the kernel.